# How do I create a Linq query that will return multiple complex properties in a sub property of a table?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

With the following classes I would like to create a Linq query for EF core that returns the object **Course** and the **Modules** in the Course and then also the **Notes** and **Chapters**

This brings back the course the modules in the course and the chapters in the modules and then the notes in the chapters (if there were any). What I want to do is bring the notes and the chapters in modules. What would be the Linq Query syntax for this query?

```
var course = context.Courses
    .Include(c => c.Modules)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.Chapters)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Notes)
    .Single(c => c.Id == courseId);
```

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    public Lab Lab { get; set; }
}

public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes {get;set;}
}

public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
var course = context.Courses
.Include(c => c.Modules)
    .ThenInclude(m => m.Chapters)
.Include(c => c.Modules)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Notes)
.Single(c => c.Id == courseId);
```

Comment: In other words, the "solution" is exactly as in official EF Core docs - [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels)